# Grafana - Collectd - GenericJMX as metric name

Tags: metrics, grafana, collectd

I'm trying to organize my metrics into grafana with collectd.

When I use the GenericJMX plugin collectd includes `GenericJMX` as part of the metric name.

[Query Grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q898C.png)

How do I configure collectd to not include `GenericJMX`?

Comment: I have the same problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might work with a rename rule like this:

```
<Chain "PreCache">
    <Rule "rename_jmx">
        <Match "regex">
            Plugin "^GenericJMX$"
        </Match>
        <Target "set">
            Plugin "java"
        </Target>
    </Rule>
</Chain>
```

This will rename 'GenericJMX' to 'java'.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can control it with `PluginName` on a per bean basis.  Unfortunately it does not seem to work on the top-level:

```
LoadPlugin java
<Plugin "java">
  # ...

  <Plugin "GenericJMX">
    # Memory usage by memory pool.
    <MBean "memory_pool">
      ObjectName "java.lang:type=MemoryPool,*"
      InstancePrefix "memory_"
      InstanceFrom "name"
      <Value>
        Type "memory"
        PluginName "jmx"
        #InstancePrefix ""
        #InstanceFrom ""
        Table true
        Attribute "Usage"
      </Value>
    </MBean>

    # ...
  </Plugin>
</Plugin>
```

[See PluginName in the docs](https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd-java.5.shtml)